# How to write unit testing for if else statements

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, mocha.js, chai

I would like to write a unit testing for a function called "fibb" using Mocha, Chai or Jasmin.

**app.js**

```
fibb: function (n) {
  if(n==1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return (n * (n-1));
  }
}
```

**test.js:**

```
var fibb = require("../app").fibb;
describe('App', function() {
  it('should be 20', function() {
    assert.equal(fibb(5), 20);
  });
});
```

This code is working for statement `2(n*(n-1))` but I want to write for both the possibilities(when ‘n==1`and`(n*(n-1))` statements).

Comment: So? Write a second test? Not sure what you're struggling with.

Comment: Write an other test "it should be one"

Comment: I want to test first statement and second statement in one test

Comment: @GabrielBleu you mean,

var fibb = require("../app").fibb;
describe('App', function() {
it('should be 1', function() {
      assert.equal(fibb(1), 1);
    });

     it('should be 20', function() {
      assert.equal(fibb(5), 20);
    });
});

Comment: @NareshAithagoni That is a bad idea, you want to test only one thing per test.

Comment: @Bentaye  


var fibb = require("../app").fibb;
describe('App', function() {
it('should be 1', function() {
      assert.equal(fibb(1), 1);
    });

     it('should be 20', function() {
      assert.equal(fibb(5), 20);
    });
});

like this?

Comment: @NareshAithagoni yes that is the idea, now when a test fails it is easy to know why, because it tests only one thing.

Comment: okay, so you mean, even if we have 10's of statements. So, we should write 10 times tests. is it? @Bentaye

Comment: @NareshAithagoni yes, if you want 100% code coverage (which you should try to tend to). it is not a problem to have a lot of tests. In the app I am working on at my work, we have thousands of unit tests, and over 90% code coverage.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot @Bentaye

Answer (score 0):

Each test case should only test one code execution path or code branch, which will be very clear. Your code uses an `if/else` statement. So, there are two branches. Without considering the boundary value, at least two test cases need to be written.

E.g.

`app.js`:

```js
const app = {
  fibb: function (n) {
    if (n == 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return n * (n - 1);
    }
  },
};

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
var fibb = require('./app').fibb;
const { assert } = require('chai');

describe('App', function () {
  it('should be 20', function () {
    assert.equal(fibb(5), 20);
  });
  it('should be 1', () => {
    assert.equal(fibb(1), 1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  App
    ✓ should be 20
    ✓ should be 1


  2 passing (4ms)
```